# Neither mail, nor mutt sends emails with file attaches

Tags: command-line, 18.04, mail, mutt, attachment

My web provider recently changed from Ubuntu 14.04 to 18.04. This broke an automated script I use to send emails with no body, but with an attach. I shortened the code below to simplfy.

This used to work until now.

```
mail -a file.txt -s "Test" me@myhome.com < /dev/null
```

The body (!) outcome was:
No attach!

```
file.txt
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="ANSI_X3.4-1968"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
```

The file itself was not attached! Only the header of the encoding was apparently sent.

Next try:

```
uuencode file.txt file.txt | mail -s "Test" me@myhome.com
```

This time, the body (!) outcome was:
No attach was shown!

```
begin 644 file.txt
M0D5'24XZ5D-!3$5.1$%2#0I615)324]..C(N,`T*4%)/1$E$.BTO+V=E;VAE
M:2!S;V9T=V%R92\O3D].4T=-3"!R;W-T;VEC<R\O14X-"DU%5$A/1#I054),
...
```

This time, the file was encoded apparently, but shown as body, not as attach.

I checked the mailbox on 2 different clients and on a webmail interface. All identical and never any attach.

`mutt` (instead of `mail`) also didn't generate file attaches. So I guess the problem is system related, not `mail` or `mutt` related.

What goes wrong here?

Comment: This made it work now: `mutt -s "Test" -a file.txt -- me@myhome.com < /dev/null`. But `mail` behaviour seems different in Ubuntu 18.04 vs 14.04. Hence my question regarding `mail` remains unanswered.

Comment: I have not checked the details but my suspicion is that the changing syntax reflects the different version of mail / nail / heirloom mail / mailx shipped by the different releases of Ubuntu...

Comment: Irrespective of possible syntax changes, `mail` should nevertheless still be capable of sending attaches somehow. I didn't manage to convice it to send any attach by any command (-a, ...) or pipe (uuencode, ...)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small variations the syntax of `Gnu Mail / heirloom mailx / nail` and friends have historically caused considerable confusion. In the case of Ubuntu 18.04 the default installation is actually `mail` from Gnu Mailutils. Tested on my own 18.04 installation:

```
andrew@corinth:~$ mail -V | head -n1
mail (GNU Mailutils) 3.4
```

In this case the correct syntax for your example would be:

```
mail -A file.txt -s "Test" me@myhome.com < /dev/null
```

Note the upper case `-A` which differs from your lower case example.

There will also be an *informational* message from `mail` complaining about the lack of a body to this email and this message can be avoided by running your example as follows, with an added option:

```
mail -E 'set nonullbodymsg' -A file.txt -s "Test" me@myhome.com < /dev/null
```

This was tested thoroughly on my own 18.04 installation and worked well, hopefully it will on yours as well :)